# Conditional Tests in Cypress using data-cy attributes as selectors

Tags: cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I see some posts about this exact topic, but none of them using data classes like I am as selectors, so it makes this conditional test a bit harder to write.

The idea is that I have a table with pagination on it. My idea is to check if the `[data-cy-pagination-next]` has or doesn't have the *disabled* attribute on it, which would mean there's more than one page and therefore the test can continue.

Most posts I see use a syntax like this:

```js
cy.get('my-button')
  .then($button => {
    if ($button.is(':enabled')) {
      cy.wrap($button).click()
    }
  })
```

But I don't have the `$button` like they described. What I would be clicking on is a button, but does that really matter?
It doesn't seem like I can write

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-next]')
  .then('[data-cy=pagination-next]' => {
    if ('[data-cy=pagination-next]'.is(':enabled')) {
      cy.wrap('[data-cy=pagination-next]').click()
    }
  })
```

How can I get this conditional to work?
If there is more than one page, this test works great, but in the cases that there is no second page, I just want the test to end there.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Here is the test currently

```js
 it('Data Source has Pagination and test functionality', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination]').should('exist')
    // assert that we are at the first page and the start and back button is disabled
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-page-list]').contains('Page 1 of')
    // If there are multiple pages then do the following tests
  
    // click next button and assert that the current page is page 2
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-next]').click()
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-page-list]').contains('Page 2 of')
    // click end button and assert that the end and next buttons are disabled
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-end]').click()
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-next]').should('be.disabled')
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-end]').should('be.disabled')
    // click start button button and assert that the current page is page 1 and next and start buttons are disabled
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-start]').click()
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-page-list]').contains('Page 1 of')
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-start]').should('be.disabled')
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-back]').should('be.disabled')
  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how yielding and callbacks work. The reason there is `$button` in the `.then()` is because it is yielded by `cy.get()`. It could be named anything, so long as it is a valid name (note: a string literal, like you are trying to do, is not valid).

So, `$button` is just the yielded element from your `cy.get('my-button')`. Which is why we can then use JQuery functions and Chai assertions on it.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-next]')
  .then($el => { // naming the yielded object from `cy.get()` to $el
    if ($el.is(':enabled')) { // using JQuery function `.is` to check if the element is enabled
      cy.wrap($el).click() // Cypress requires the JQuery element to be wrapped before it can click it.
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown. I didn't know that I would need to know any JQuery for Cypress, but just the breakdown that because the element is yielded by `cy.get()` and that it can be named anything is really helpful. I knew the string literal was not valid, I was just trying to figure out WHAT it could be named by posting this. 

Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. JQuery isn't _needed_ for Cypress, but knowing some basics of how it works helps out (since Cypress is built on top of it!)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the page indicator to split the test logic

```js
it('Data Source has Pagination and test functionality', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination]').should('exist')

    cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-page-list]')
    .then($pageList => {

      if ($pageList.text() === 'Page 1 of 1')  

        // single page assertions

        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-next]').should('be.disabled')
        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-end]').should('be.disabled')
        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-start]').should('be.disabled')
        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-back]').should('be.disabled')

      } else {

        // multi page assertions
  
        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-next]').click()
        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-page-list]')
          .should('contain', 'Page 2 of')            // assert on second page

        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-end]').click()
        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-next]').should('be.disabled')

        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-start]').click()
        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-page-list]').contains('Page 1 of')
        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-start]').should('be.disabled')
        cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-back]').should('be.disabled')
     }
  })
```

Better still, control the test data so that only a single page exists, then run two tests under known conditions and eliminate flaky conditional testing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! 
My thing with these types of assertions is that I don't know how many pages there are really so I figured it was enough to test the first `next` button and check if the it's on the second page, then click the `end` button and assert that both `next` and `end` buttons are disabled. Same goes for the left side buttons, `back` and `start`. This way it works if there is just one page or multi-pages.

Comment: Indeed, testing if `Page 1 of 1` does all of that. You don't need to know how many pages, or check the condition of the next button.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. You can use an `each` to loop over all the pagination elements. So in case, you don't have only 2 buttons the loop will check for only 2 buttons and then terminate.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-page-list]').should('contain.text', 'Page 1 of')
cy.get('[data-cy=pagination-next]').each(($ele, index) => {
  if ($ele.is(':enabled')) {
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
    cy.wrap($ele).should('contain.text', `Page ${index + 2} of`) //index starts from 0
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! This loop using each was great advice! I probably should have said, but I have 4 buttons a `start` and `back` on the left and `next` and `end` on the right. I definitely need to test for the `start` and `end` buttons to make sure they jump to the beginning and end of the table pages, but your comment really helped me out!
Cheers!